# android adb fails to recognise Asus ZenPad 8.0

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, asus

I am trying to connect an Asus ZenPad 8.0 Z380M to adb running within Eclipse on a Windows 8.1 system.

When I try to launch the debugger I get the Android Device Chooser dialogue but no devices are listed.
I have enabled USB debugging on the tablet and have modified the android_winusb.inf file to add the following entries:

```
; Asus ZenPad 8.0 in File Transfer mode
;%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0E8D&PID_2016&REV_????&MI_00
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0E8D&PID_2016
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0E8D&PID_2016&MI_00

; Asus ZenPad 8.0 in Photo Transfer mode
;%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0E8D&PID_2015&REV_????&MI_00
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0E8D&PID_2015
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0E8D&PID_2015&MI_00
```

using the VID and PID obtained from Windows Device Manager.  When I do a manual install of the device driver and browse to the android_winusb.inf file the installer prompts me with 'Android Composite ADB Interface' as expected, and the installation completes (after I have allowed it to install an uncertified driver).  Device Manager shows it correctly in the device tree, and shows that the Google USB driver is installed.  But nothing shows up in Android Device Chooser.

I have set up several other tablets this way without problems, but one thing which is different is that they all have hardware IDs ending in &MI_01 rather then &MI_00.  Is that significant?

Comment: It's 2017 brother. Still Eclipse? Its officially unsupported. Switch to -> Android Studio

Comment: I realise that, but I am nearing the end of a project that started while Studio was still in beta, and we chose not to switch horses in mid-stream.  As soon as the product has been released we will switch over.  However, even Studio uses adb according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) so I will probably have the same problem.